# How I can insert all response from server into clear class of answer?

Tags: android

In my application I get response from server which contains all important information about my received letters. You can see a sample of such response:

```
    {
    "count": int, # number of messages 
    "messages": [ # array of messages
        {
            "id": int, # message id
            "subject": str, # message subject
            "can_delete": bool, # can it be deleted (True) or not (False)
            "new": int # message already read (0) or not (1)
            "date": str, # date of message in 'd.m.y'. If message was sent today format will be 'H:M'
            "receiver_name": str, # name of receiver if type=1
            "sender_name": str, # name of sender if type=0
        }, ...
    ],
    "next_url": URL,  # url for get next messages, if no more messages value is null
    "previous_url": URL # url for get previous messages, if no more messages value is null
}
```

and as I understand I have to create a class which will contain all similiar fields and then I will use it for fetching the following information into some adapters. But I can't understand how I have to write these all fields at my class. I have to create all similiar with the sample of my response, like count, or array of messages??? I can't understand the way of creating this array at all, because I saw that I have to insert some data into my array initialization.

### Thank you for your positive answers and advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you need, you have to create a model (class) with the same structure of your response. Then you can parse it into an object and easily process the datas.

Your model is something like this:

```
public class MyMessage{
    private int id;
    private String subject;
    private boolean can_delete;
    @SerializedName("new") //this is because new is a protected keyword. this annotation is for Gson parsing library. Any library has his own annotation
    private int newField;
    private String date;
    private String receiver_name;
    private String sender_name;

    public MyMessage(){}

    //here getters and setters
}
public class ResponseMessage{
    private int count;
    private List<MyMessage> messages;
    private String next_url;
    private String previous_url;

    public ResponseMessage() {
    }

    //here getters and setters
}
```

Note: obv the class you need to use for json parsing is the `ResponseMessage` one.

**Please note that the `new` field has some problems with the keyword. You will need to call it in another way and specify the `serializedName` of that property.**

Hope this helps

## Edit: I would suggest using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). It is really intuitive and easy.

A simple usage for your case would be this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ResponseMessage myWebResponse = gson.fromJson(inputString, ResponseMessage.class);
```

Where `ResponseMessage` is your deserialized object, and `inputString` is your json string :)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have some question for your answer:

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko no problem, ask freely :)

Comment: I will write you as soon as I will formulate it, because I need to understand it at all)))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko I added an example using Gson, please have a look

Comment: I have formulated one question about your edition: where I have to use the following part of code. Because I use api for creating request. And one more question: which class I have to write at my api request?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko you should add the code you are using to retrieve data from server

Comment: so the following code (which is connected with gson) is created for retrieving data from server responce?? because right now I can use your code but I can't realize how I can create listview or resycleview with all following information?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko implementing the server call-response is another problem :) here is supposed that you already have made the server call. If you want to perform a get or a post, I would suggest OkHttp library, but it's long to explain here, there are plenty of questions about it, try having a look :)

Comment: ok, thank you for your so useful answers because it is difficult for me and I'm looking for information everywhere))

Comment: no problem! It looks like you are a beginner for Android, if you want to invest time, watch [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y). It helped really a lot for me when I started :) good luck!